# python: adding timedeltas, int unsupported operand type

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

frames_load = 0
times_start_dict = [{'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 23)}, {'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 23)}]
times_end_dict = [{'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 53)}, {'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 53)}]

for start in times_start_dict:
    for end in times_end_dict:         
        if check_startend(): #dummy function to check other value in dict to see if start/end times match; please comment this out and indent code block to reproduce error
            frames_load += end['timestamp'] - start['timestamp']
            print frames_load
            continue
```

Output:

```
Traceback (line 11): "frames_load += end['timestamp'] - start['timestamp']"

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

**Some context:**

I'm iterating over two lists consisting of `dict`s which contain `datetime` objects for start and end times, respectively. Once a start and end `timedelta` have been correctly matched (not shown), I find the time elapsed which becomes a `timedelta` object. I'm assigning it to `frames_load` so that in the next iteration, I can add the time elapsed (which should always be positive), figuring it's just like incrementing `x += 1`. However, I'm getting a `TypeError` which says to me that after the first iteration/calculation, `frames_load` is now an `int` and no longer a `timedelta` object.

How can I add `timedelta`s to `frames_load` so that it can display the aggregate/sum `timedelta`?

Comment: Your error message does not match your code block, see the `int(...)`.

Comment: @Nabla Thanks for the edit, I'm new to posting/commenting on stack. What do you mean my error does not match the code block? I wrote this to represent my code and error, so perhaps you're pointing to a discrepancy I don't see. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @nabla do you mean that the error int cannot be added to a timedelta object does not match with line 4?

Comment: The line you posted in the code is `frames_load += end['timestamp'] - start['timestamp']`. The same line in the error traceback reads `frames_load += int(end['timestamp'] - start['timestamp'])`. So the code is not the same code that produced the error. This makes it hard to give a precise answer. Also you should show minimal code initializing `frames_load` and best `times_start_dict` and `times_end_dict` as well, so everyone can reproduce the error.

Comment: You already have the answer from @alko: instead of `frames_load = 0` use `frames_load = timedelta()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this code could not output `00:00:35`, as `frames_load=0` initially.

Second, error says it all, you can't add timedelta, i.e. `end['timestamp'] - start['timestamp']`, to integer, that is to `0`.

If you want sum up cumulative timedelta, you should init `frames_load=timedelta()`. Or following code will do the trick:

```
times_start_dict = [{'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 23)}, 
                    {'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 23)}]
times_end_dict = [{'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 25)}, 
                  {'timestamp': datetime(2013, 12, 21, 4, 36, 26)}]
print sum((end['timestamp'] - start['timestamp'] 
             for start, end in zip(times_start_dict, times_end_dict)),
          timedelta())

# 0:00:05
```

Comment: Awesome thank you @alko, nabla, and others who contributed. I had tried a similar approach to initialize `frames_load` to datetime.timedelta() but that errored. I guess it's the datetime module is implicitly invoked here?